# Image links not working in footer

Tags: html

http://www.artwars.net

Please take a look at the footer with logos two of the logos links bedpr and stormtrooper aren't working.

It is better to view the code through the browser than me paste it.

Appreciate the help.

Ant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your markup is messy:

```
<div id="logo118" <a href="http://www.bedpr.com/"><img src="http://www.artwars.net/wp-content/themes/artwars2/images/bedpr.jpg" width="145" height="40"></div>
```

That's no valid HTML. You should close the starting div tag. I think you forgot the ">".

**edit:**

Take a look at the div's: The swarowski logo's div is missing

```
float:left; //So just add it there.
```

Also it has a

```
margin-left:360px;
```

instead of

```
left:360px; //This should not force design problems, just to improve your layout
```

Now, you have to adjust logo113 and logo115. Just like this:

```
top:-20px; //instead of -50px
```

Should work now.

Comment: No that was just a sloppy error, now fixed, it's still not working however, I think it might be to do with the css, but I've always done it this way and always worked......hmmmm

Comment: So basically the Swarowski div/box model was on top of the others due to the way I was laying out, not letting the floats do the work, when I was clicking on bedpr swarowski was highlighting, therefore preventing the link working........now works fine......let the floats do the work and position from there.......thanks